# i am facing with a error :Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client ,anybody hel me

Tags: node.js

C:\Users\KUMAR\Desktop\DigitelMall\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\KUMAR\Desktop\DigitelMall\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\KUMAR\Desktop\DigitelMall\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:163:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\KUMAR\Desktop\DigitelMall\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:249:15)
    at updateEntity (C:\Users\KUMAR\Desktop\DigitelMall\controllers\MainMenu.js:81:40)
    at Query.pool.query (C:\Users\KUMAR\Desktop\DigitelMall\models\CommonModel.js:110:20)
    at Query. (C:\Users\KUMAR\Desktop\DigitelMall\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (C:\Users\KUMAR\Desktop\DigitelMall\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\KUMAR\Desktop\DigitelMall\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)

Comment: please post the endpoint implementation for this request

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send the response to a request that you had already responded to.

The response could have been sent by the framework you are using if it implements a default error handler.